# ERROR in HostResourceResolver: could not resolve in angular

Tags: angular, resources, host, resolver

i'm learning Angular. I've a bug with routes

```
ERROR in HostResourceResolver: could not resolve ./app/detail-pokemon.component.html in context of //pokemon-app/pokemon-app/src/app/detail-pokemon.component.ts)
```

Can you help me ?

thx

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was not providing the `templateUrl`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'whoami',
  templateUrl: ""
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

after providing a valid template url, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I created a component using CLI with additional component suffix (resulted in double naming) and renamed it back then (I changed it in templateUrl from `login-component.component.html` to `login-component.html` instead of `login.component.html`)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had templateUrl and the actual file name differed a capitalized and non-capitalized character.

File name was `detailContent.component.html`

TemplateUrl was `detailcontent.component.html`